# PHP PDO MSSQL connect переписывает результата выборки?

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

Что то непонятное, прошу помощи. Не то что бы непонятное. Но вот.

Есть тех. сайт с MSSQL.

В конфиге подключение:

```
$pdo_options = array(
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
    PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true,
);

try{ 
    $sql_mssqlconnect = new PDO ("dblib:host=". DB_MS_HOST .";dbname=". DB_MS_NAME. "","". DB_MS_USER ."","". DB_MS_PASS ."");
}  
catch(PDOException $sql_mssqlconnect_e)
{  
    echo ("Ошибка подключения к базе данных MSSQL<b>". DB_MS_NAME ."</b>. SQL erorr: ". $sql_tmkconnect_e->getMessage() ."");
    die();
};
```

на странице делаю выгрузку, условно, заказами, обхожу список и подгружаю, условно, сумму контактов через класс, вызываемый через передачу ему переменной подключения к базе данных и ID контракта

```
$query = $sql_mssqlconnect ->query("SELECT * FROM  table_zakaz");
$query->execute();
while ($result = $query->fetch())
{
    $class = new summ($sql_mssqlconnect, $id_zakaza);
```

#получаю данные из класса и что то там делаю
};

Вот тут как раз непонятная "подстава", выгружается только 1 данные из 1 запроса. Если создать отельное подключение $sql_mssqlconnect2 и использовать в подсчёте суммы контрактов, то считет все хорошо. То есть результаты подзапроса перетирают результат основного запроса и цикл обхода останавливается.

Что происходит? Что погуглить?  С MySQL PDO такого не происходит.

Comment: 1) не надо выполнять подобные вещи в цикле, можно а) написать подзапрос в основном б) использовать группировку, а запросы в цикле это лютое зло. 2) подготовка выражения делается не просто так, а чтобы единожды закэшировать план его выполнения. Ключевое слово - единожды, то есть сделать надо это перед циклом, и вызывать запрос с разными параметрами. В виду первого, второе уже не требуется.

Comment: а не работает у вас ничего, потому что под оба запроса вы используете одну переменную. переписав ее внутри цикла, перестает работать условие. к ms/mysql это отношения не имеет, а имеет только к вашей внимательности

Comment: в целом  у вас там должно быть `$sql = "select id, ... , (select sum() from where ...) from ...` потом `$result = $pdo->fetchAll()` и цикл вывода

Comment: 1) можно выполнять подобные вещи в цикле, это способ достичь результата, да я знаю что это "лютое" зло, но в моем масштабе - все равно.

Comment: Усложним задачу (вернее к исходному, что бы исключить кривые переменные), подсчет суммы контактов идет через вызываемый класс, в которой предаётся подключение и ID заказа.
$class = new summ($sql_mssqlconnect, $id_zakaza);

он там что то считает, и возвращает разные данные.

Так вот, при таких условиях так же цикл опроса останавливается, если использовать одну и тоже переменную подключения к MSSQL.

на MySQL такого не происходит.

Comment: давайте тогда код целиком что ли, и что вам мешает таки сделать fetchAll сразу первому массиву? он большой что ли что не хочется в память выгружать? по крайней мере это точно решит вашу проблему

Comment: в этом то и вопрос, почему fetchAll возвращает только 1 строку при использовании такого же $sql_mssqlconnect экземпляра подключения к базе данных, при использовании копии с именем $sql_mssqlconnect_two возвращает все из выборки и класс отрабатывает правильно.